# Count all items in the list in dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that hs 2 columns

```
Text           Categories
"Hi Hello"     [F35, B3, C98]
"Where is"     [G58, F35, C17]
"Is she?!"     [T92, F35, B3]
```

the field `Categories` is an array of Categories

I want to find how many distinct Categories I have

I tried this code but did not work

```
print(len(sorted(set(df['Categories']))))
```

I tried this but it was just for one record !

```
print(len(sorted(set(df['Categories'][0]))))
```

I did not know how to do it for all categories in the dataframe?

Comment: `df['Categories'].explode().value_counts()`

Comment: Are you searching for unique values within each array, or are you searching for unique values for each Category across all arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you unique categories.

```
In [128]: df = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:     'Text': ["Hi Hello", "Where is","Is she?!"],
     ...:     'Categories': [["F35", "B3", "C98"],["G58", "F35", "C17"],["G58", "F35", "C17"]]
     ...: })
In [131]: set(df["Categories"].explode())
Out[131]: {'B3', 'C17', 'C98', 'F35', 'G58'}
```

Credits to @DanielGeffen - You can also use `df["Categories"].explode().unique()`

Comment: You can also use pandas `unique` function instead of `set`: `df["Categories"].explode().unique()`